# Is there a python function, that allows to move and resize windows?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a python module, that can move&resize windows(any windows,not just made with python).
In C there is a win32 api function, called SetWindowPos().
Is there any alternative for python.
*Web searches gave me nothing, but tk module resize function, which only works with its own(tk) windows.

Comment: Not sure if it is at all possible with raw Python, but if you're familiar with a C api, then why not use C-code within your Python code? [Extending Python with C/C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Comment: this may help http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/pywo-python-window-organizer-easily.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is! Based on your question, I'm assuming you're getting at something similar to the programming language, AHK. There is a python library, *ahk* which takes advantage of that language.

PyPi link: https://pypi.org/project/ahk/

Github link: https://github.com/spyoungtech/ahk